# cocoa - converting a double to string

Tags: iphone, cocoa, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a double number and I would like to convert it to string.

The number is, for example, something like

**24.043333332154465777...**

but if I convert it to string using something like

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", myDouble];
```

The string is just

24.043333

how do I get a full string the corresponds to the whole double number? What other methods do I have to convert this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Another option, since you asked for other ways in your comment to mipadi's answer:

Create an `NSNumber` using `NSNumber *myDoubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:myDouble];`

Then call `[myDoubleNumber stringValue];`

From the docs:

> Returns the receiver’s value as a human-readable string, created by invoking descriptionWithLocale: where locale is nil.

Comment: both methods - yours and mipadi's - are perfect for the conversion, but for some reason, mipadi's gave me a string that was slightly different of the original number. Your's give me the same number... thanks.

Answer (score 23):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.20f", myDouble];
```

or

```
@(myDouble).stringValue;
```

Answer (score 13):

You can pass a width format specifier to `stringWithFormat`.

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.20f", myDouble];
```

will format `myDouble` with 20 decimal places.

Comment: thanks!!! Just a final question. Is this the only way to convert a double to string? I mean, using stringWithFormat?

Comment: @Hafthor: No need for `lf`. `f` is the format specifier for a double, as noted in the Cocoa string documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) and this question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4264154/28804).

Answer (score 2):

There's also [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/).

Answer (score 2):

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", myDouble];

Use this for no decimal value