# Correct format specifier for double in printf

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, double, format-specifiers

What is the correct format specifier for `double` in `printf`? Is it `%f` or is it `%lf`? I believe it's `%f`, but I am not sure.

#### Code sample

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   double d = 1.4;
   printf("%lf", d); // Is this wrong?
}
```

Comment: If you're stuck with a C89 library, `"%lf"` is undefined; in C99 and C11 libraries it is defined to be the same as `"%f"`.

Comment: Your variant is as correct as it ever gets. `%lf` is the correct format specifier for `double`. But it became so in C99. Before that one had to use `%f`.

Answer (score 797, accepted):

`"%f"` is the (or at least one) correct format for a double. There *is* no format for a `float`, because if you attempt to pass a `float` to `printf`, it'll be promoted to `double` before `printf` receives it<sup>1</sup>. `"%lf"` is also acceptable under the current standard -- the `l` is specified as having no effect if followed by the `f` conversion specifier (among others).

Note that this is one place that `printf` format strings differ substantially from `scanf` (and `fscanf`, etc.) format strings. For output, you're passing a *value*, which will be promoted from `float` to `double` when passed as a variadic parameter. For input you're passing a *pointer*, which is not promoted, so you have to tell `scanf` whether you want to read a `float` or a `double`, so for `scanf`, `%f` means you want to read a `float` and `%lf` means you want to read a `double` (and, for what it's worth, for a `long double`, you use `%Lf` for either `printf` or `scanf`).

---

<sub>1. C99, §6.5.2.2/6: "If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to double. These are called the default argument promotions." In C++ the wording is somewhat different (e.g., it doesn't use the word "prototype") but the effect is the same: all the variadic parameters undergo default promotions before they're received by the function.</sub>

Comment: Note that `g++` rejects `%lf` when compiling with `-Wall -Werror -pedantic`: `error: ISO C++ does not support the ‘%lf’ gnu_printf format`

Comment: @kynan: If so (at leas assuming a current version of g++), that's a bug in g++. For C89/90 and C++98/03, allowing `l` was an extension. The C99/11 and C++11 standards require the implementation to allow it.

Comment: Seems only g++ 4.7 chokes on it, it works on 4.6. It's triggered by the format warning i.e. `-Wno-format` is enough to make it compile.

Comment: Curiously, `scanf` *does* want `double`s represented by `%lf`: it complains that it expected `float *` and found `double *` with just `%f`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin g++ still defaults to g++98 mode

Comment: @EricDand That's because `scanf` takes pointers to where to store what it reads, so _needs_ to know how big the space being pointed-at is, whereas `printf` takes the values themselves, and "default argument promotions" mean both end up as `double`s, so the `l` is essentially optional.

Comment: A _pointer_ is a _type_. Specifically, there requires the value of a pointer type, instead of the value of the object being pointed to.

Answer (score 66):

Given the [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) standard (namely, the *N1256* draft), the rules depend on the
function kind: fprintf (printf, sprintf, ...) or scanf.

Here are relevant parts extracted:

> **Foreword**
>
> This second edition cancels and replaces the first edition, ISO/IEC 9899:1990, as amended and corrected by ISO/IEC 9899/COR1:1994, ISO/IEC 9899/AMD1:1995, and ISO/IEC 9899/COR2:1996.
>   Major changes from the previous edition include:
>
> - `%lf` conversion specifier allowed in `printf`
>
> **7.19.6.1 The `fprintf` function**
>
> **7** The length modifiers and their meanings are:
>
> *l* (ell) Specifies that (...) has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier.
>
> *L* Specifies that a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier applies to a long double argument.

The same rules specified for `fprintf` apply for `printf`, `sprintf` and similar functions.

> **7.19.6.2 The `fscanf` function**
>
> **11** The length modifiers and their meanings are:
>
> *l* (ell) Specifies that (...) that a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to double;
>
> *L* Specifies that a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion
>   specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to long double.
>
> **12** The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>        a,e,f,g Matches an optionally signed floating-point number, (...)
>
> **14** The conversion specifiers A, E, F, G, and X are also valid and behave the same as, respectively, a, e, f, g, and x.

The long story short, for `fprintf` the following specifiers and corresponding types are specified:

- `%f`  -> double
- `%Lf` -> long double.

and for `fscanf` it is:

- `%f`  -> float
- `%lf` -> double
- `%Lf` -> long double.

Answer (score 37):

It can be `%f`, `%g` or `%e` depending on how you want the number to be formatted. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Type_field) for more details. The `l` modifier is required in `scanf` with `double`, but not in `printf`.

Comment: -1: `l` (lowercase) modifier is for integer types (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/), and `L` is for floating point types. Additionally, the `L` modifier expects a `long double`, not a plain `double`.

Comment: user470379: So where is the contradiction with my answer? Haven't I said that `l` is not required in `printf` for `double`.

Comment: For `printf`, the length modifier `l` is ignored in the case of floating point types because float arguments are always promoted to double. Jerry Coffin's answer has more information.

Answer (score 21):

Format `%lf` is a perfectly correct `printf` format for `double`, exactly as you used it. There's nothing wrong with your code.

Format `%lf` in `printf` was not supported in old (pre-C99) versions of C language, which created superficial "inconsistency" between format specifiers for `double` in `printf` and `scanf`. That superficial inconsistency has been fixed in C99.

You are not required to use `%lf` with `double` in `printf`. You can use `%f` as well, if you so prefer (`%lf` and `%f` are equivalent in `printf`). But in modern C it makes perfect sense to prefer to use `%f` with `float`, `%lf` with `double` and `%Lf` with `long double`, consistently in both `printf` and `scanf`.

Comment: With `scanf()`, `"%f"`, `"%lf"` match a `float *, double *`, not `float, double` as implied by the last line.

Answer (score 13):

`%Lf` (note the capital `L`) is the [format specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) for [long doubles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double).

For plain `doubles`, either `%e`, `%E`, `%f`, `%g` or `%G` will do.

Comment: What's the difference between `%g` and `%G` ?

Comment: @yanpas, lowercase / uppercase for the exponent symbol, respectively.

Comment: sorry, %g and %G do output E symbol. Also they output INF and inf in different cases