# parsing NSString to Double

Tags: objective-c

so I want to convert `NSString` to double. I found the following example:

```
NSString * s = @"1.5e5";
NSLog(@"%lf", [s doubleValue]);
```

It works but if `doubleValue` cannot convert the string to double it simply returns 0.0 which is not what I need. I need some method that tries to convert a string representation of double to double and if indicate somehow if it can't be converted.
c# has an excellent method

```
double d;
boolean Double.TryParse(str, out d)
```

Is there any method similar to the above one in Objective C? or maybe it's better to use regex? however, i don't really know how to do that.

Comment: Another example of people thinking that regex is the ultimate magic solution for everything and that it brings world peace...

Comment: By the way, what you're doing is **undefined behavior.** I won't be surprised if it printed out the correct value if you used `%lf` instead of `%f` (which is for `float`s and not for `double`s...)

Comment: @H2CO3: According to [String Programming Guide/Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), `%f` works with `float` and `double` when formatting. Only for scanning you have to differentiate.

Comment: @MartinR Strange. Upper on the same page it's written that NSString format specifiers support everything `printf()` does - and for printf, `%f` is for floats and `%lf` is for doubles, and using them interchangeably is undefined behavior.

Comment: @H2CO3: I am not an expert on this, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf states that `%f` can be used for `double`. That is also what I understand from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html.

Comment: @MartinR Bingo! Asked the poster of the answer you linked and he explained how default type promotion with variadic functions works. You're right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `NSScanner` class:

```
NSString *s = @"1.5e5";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:s];
double d;
BOOL success = [scanner scanDouble:&d];
```

If you want to ensure that the entire string has been scanned (no extra characters after the number), use

```
BOOL isAtEnd = [scanner isAtEnd];
```