# Objective-C (Mac) try-catch not catching exception

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Here's my method:

```
- (IBAction)calculateButton:(id)sender {
    NSInteger dividend = 0;
    NSInteger divisor = 0;

    @try {
        dividend = [dividendField integerValue];
        divisor = [divisorField integerValue];
        [quotientField setIntegerValue: dividend / divisor]; //program crashes here
        [remainderField setIntegerValue: dividend % divisor];
    }

    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSAlert* alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
        [alert setMessageText: @"Error"];
        [alert setInformativeText: @"Invalid input!"];
        [alert runModal];
    }

}
```

The way I understood it `NSException` is a general exception handler that all the other exceptions inherit from; so the question is, why does the program crash instead of going into the `@catch` block? I get an `EXC_ARITHMETIC` which by my understanding is still an exception... So why doesn't the `@catch` catch it?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but generally exception handling is *very* rarely used in Objective C.  This particular error is the archetypical example of where you should use a test instead.

Comment: but why is exception handling rarely used? if it's something that causes the program to crash, it needs to be handled... right?

Comment: Exception in Objective-C/Cocoa tend to mean programmer error, dived by zero is something you can test for. Exceptions are not very Object Orientated, exception fall through to callers methods and are not handled in an OOP way, other than having an object represent them

Comment: @ElectricCoffee you test for zero before actually dividing. Since math does not define a result when you divide by zero you probably want to handle this as a special case anyway.

Comment: but the whole issue is that I need to check if someone puts text into the box and not numbers... division by zero isn't the problem

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Then parse the string into numbers and detect errors during the parsing process.

Comment: @trojanfoe isn't that exactly what `integerValue` does? parse the string to an int I mean

Comment: @ElectricCoffee No, not exactly, as it will return `0` if the text isn't a valid number.  Better is to write your own solution around `strtol()` and friends, and they *do* allow error detection.

Comment: @trojanfoe that didn't make any difference

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Nevermind; this is going off-topic anyway.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865981/parsing-nsstring-to-double

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the "exception" is not an Objective-C exception but an exception/trap from the kernel. The division by zero is not handled in objects, therefore pure C rules apply here.