# NSNumberFormatter numberFromString decimal number

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to parse a `NSString` with a `NSNumberFormatter` like following.

```
NSNumberFormatter *myFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber *myNumber = [myFormatter numberFromString:@"42.00000"];
```

`numberFromString` returns a `NSNumber` object in the simulator but not on a device.

The decimals (.00000) are causing the return value to be nil on a device because parsing 42 (without the decimals) works just fine (both in the simulator and on a device).

The reason I'm using a NSNumberFormatter is because is like how it returns `nil` if the string is not a valid number (which is working against me here :p). NSString `doubleValue` does not provide this kind of behaviour. Also, `NSDecimalNumber` `decimalNumberWithString` doesn't do the job because `[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"4a2.00000"]` returns 4.

Any ideas why this would not work on a device?

Is it the locale? I tried setting `myFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterNoStyle` and `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` but it changes nothing.

Comment: Parsing `42.00000` will only work if the device's (or simulator's) locale is set to a locale that uses the period for the decimal separator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @rmaddy already said in a comment, the decimal separator of `NSNumberFormatter` is
locale dependent. If you have a fixed input format with the dot as decimal separator,
you can set the "POSIX locale":

```
NSNumberFormatter *myFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[myFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
NSNumber *myNumber = [myFormatter numberFromString:@"42.00000"];
```

Alternatively, you can use `NSScanner` to parse a double value, as e.g. described
here: [parsing NSString to Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865981/parsing-nsstring-to-double)

Comment: Thx, that works, what is the difference between en_US_POSIX and en_US?

Comment: @user3250560: I don't know the formal definition, but in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html (which is about *dates*, where similar locale dependent problems occur), it is described as *... "en_US_POSIX", a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences. "en_US_POSIX" is also invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the way it formats dates, "en_US" will change to reflect the new behaviour, but "en_US_POSIX" will not), and between machines ...*

Answer (score 1):

`42.00000` is not a string mate, why not `@"42.00000"`?

Comment: That's a typo in the question. The OP states it works fine in the simulator.