# NSNumberFormatter inside a computed Property

Tags: swift, properties, nsnumberformatter

i am trying to format a string to a number with NSNumberFormatter.
My code looks like this:

```
var displayValue: Double? {
    get {
        let i = "4.2"
        return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(i)?.doubleValue
    }
}
```

The property is always **nil**, what am i missing?

Comment: Probably a locale issue. Does it work with "4,2" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413605/nsnumberformatter-numberfromstring-decimal-number (which is written in Objective-C, but the  problem and the solution are identical in Swift).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r)! is right it was a locale issue "4,2" works fine, thanks!