# Gcc compiler option to convert int arg to double?

Tags: c, gcc, casting

I made the assumption that int args passed for double parameters would be converted to doubles. For example

I am calling: 
    make_line(root, "hi", 5,5,50,50);

on:

```
GooCanvasItem * make_line(GooCanvasItem * parent, char * name, gdouble x1, gdouble y1, gdouble x2, gdouble y2)
{
    printf("from make line: %f %f %f %f\n", x1, y1, x2, y2);
    //...
}
```

the `printf` produces:

```
from make line: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

when I call it with

```
make_line(root, "hi", 5.0,5.0,50.0,50.0);
```

it gives the correct output.

Changing `gdouble` to `double` doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: can you rephrase the question or better post an example?

Comment: `add(5)` would not cast `a` to 0.

Comment: why would `5` be cast to `0`? it would cast to `5.0` if any. am I missing something?

Comment: Sharing your code and the execution output would help us get the fact. In any case add(5) would not cast 'a' to 0. Please review your code.

Comment: Is the function prototype for `add` visible at the point where you're calling it?  Are you compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`?

Comment: Where did you get this assumption in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

`a` (5) won't be converted into `0`.

I believe you are using `%d` in your `printf` instead of `%f` for printing double values. Turn on the compiler warnings when you compile your code.

Use `-Wformat` option of gcc.

Comment: @Ayub: In C standard, `%lf` -> `scanf`.

Comment: @Ayub Nope :) See: [Correct format specifier for double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. :) Good that many eyes are there to fix little mistakes. :D

Comment: @mihajlv What's `gdouble`? how is it defined?

Comment: @mihajlv `Changing gdouble to double doesn't seem to fix the problem.` This can't be true. Here's the simplified demo: http://ideone.com/Bwan2d

Comment: @KingsIndian I know, it is wierd gdouble is just the c double used by glib, I think it has to do something with the glib library.