# Reading in double values with scanf in c

Tags: c, scanf, conversion-specifier

I try to read-in 2 values using scanf() in C, but the values the system writes into memory are not equal to my entered values. Here is the code:

```
double a,b;
printf("--------\n"); //seperate lines
scanf("%ld",&a);
printf("--------\n"); 
scanf("%ld",&b);
printf("%d %d",a,b);
```

If I enter 1 and 2, CMD returns a correct, but b = -858993460 Here is what I already tried:
using float or int instead of double, using scanf_s, using scanf("%d or %f for %i or %li or %lf or %e or %g ), using fflush(stdin) to clear keyboard buffer, reading in b first, trying like all possible combinations. I found out that there is a problem with the length of double on 32 bit OS, so that you are forced to use scanf("%lf", &f) to read in a double. No matter what I do, second value is always wrong.

I use MS VS express 2012 for Desktop on Windows 7 32 bit OS.

Comment: Rolled back to rev 3 as the change rendered answers ununderstandable.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Use the `%lf` format specifier to read a double:

```
double a;
scanf("%lf",&a);
```

Wikipedia has a [decent reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string) for available format specifiers.

You'll need to use the `%lf` format specifier to print out the results as well:

```
printf("%lf %lf",a,b);
```

Comment: tried it already, does only work for the first value, second is still wrong.

Comment: Much as I love Wikipedia, a decent basic C book might be an even better recommendation for the OP (+1)

Comment: @NPE Fair point.  I thought a recommendation to "read a good book" might be viewed as a bit vague though and the wikipedia page was, surprisingly, the best reference I could find.

Comment: @user1880009 You were still using the `%d` format specifier to print the results.  This resulted in only 4 bytes of your double being read and interpreted as an int.  You need to use the `%lf` format specifier here too.  I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: ty, this works, at least for the first 2 values. i tried it with three, the first two are ok but the third is wrong, though using ur solution.

Comment: ah, my bad, misstyped, now working for everything, ty 4 help :)

Comment: `%lf` to print a double was added in C99;  if you want to be compatible with older versions of C then `%f` can be used which prints both `float` and `double`.

Comment: Tell yourself: `%lf` = **L**ong **F**loat = `double`.

Answer (score 8):

As far as i know `%d` means decadic which is number without decimal point. if you want to load double value, use `%lf` conversion (long float). for printf your values are wrong for same reason, `%d` is used only for integer (and possibly chars if you know what you are doing) numbers.

Example:

```
double a,b;
printf("--------\n"); //seperate lines
scanf("%lf",&a);
printf("--------\n"); 
scanf("%lf",&b);
printf("%lf %lf",a,b);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using wrong formatting sequence for `double`, you should use `%lf` instead of `%ld`:

```
double a;
scanf("%lf",&a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Format specifier in `printf` should be `%f` for `doubl` datatypes since `float` datatyles eventually convert to `double` datatypes inside `printf`.

There is no provision to print `float` data.  Please find the discussion here :  [Correct format specifier for double in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf)

Comment: While this is true, the question is about scanf, which has historically behaved differently than printf, which didn't support %lf until C99. Unlike scanf, which the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code when scanning the second value:
`scanf(" %lf", &b);`
also replace all %ld with %lf.

It's a problem related with input stream buffer. You can also use fflush(stdin); after the first scanning to clear the input buffer and then the second scanf will work as expected. An alternate way is place a getch(); or getchar(); function after the first scanf line.

Answer (score 0):

Correct ways is:

```
double a,b;
printf("--------\n"); //seperate lines
scanf("%lf",&a);        //%lf is long float numbers 
printf("--------\n"); 
scanf("%lf",&b);
printf("%f %f",a,b);     //%f float number
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: all description is in code  " //%lf is long float numbers "

Answer (score -5):

Using `%lf` will help you in solving this problem.

Use :

```
scanf("%lf",&doub)
```

Comment: What's new/different in this answer? The same has been posted 4 years before this.