# sqrt function in C prints -nan

Tags: c, sqrt

While doing some code excercise,
I observed unusual ouput caused by the sqrt funtion,

The code was,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    double l,b,min_r,max_r;
    int i;
    scanf("%lf %lf",&b,&l);
    printf("%lf %lf\n",sqrt(l*l+b*b),sqrt(b*b-l*l));
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
4 5
6.403124 -nan
```

Why does this happenes.

Comment: for printing a `double`, `%f` will suffice.

Comment: (4*4-5*5)=-9 which is less than 0. sqrt() of a negative number is not a real number.

Comment: %f is not a problem here. @SouravGhosh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730188/reading-in-double-values-with-scanf-in-c @SouravGhosh

Comment: I'm telling again... for double %f is enough. but in this post, %f isn't problem. The only problem was, he was trying to print square root of a negative number. @SouravGhosh

Comment: and for @MukitChowdhury, please do read the [lastest comment on the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730188/reading-in-double-values-with-scanf-in-c#comment42275373_13730228) of the question you pointed. Thanks.

Comment: @DarkDust Just to let you know, I did not mean to be rude, at all. :) Cheers!! (Let's remove the comment chain...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the numbers:  `b` is 4 and `l` is 5.  So `b*b - l*l` is -9.  What's the square root of -9?  It's an imaginary number, but `sqrt` doesn't support imaginary results, so the result is nan (not a number).  It's a domain error.  The solution:  Don't pass negative arguments to `sqrt`.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, not validating the inputs cause the issue.

```
sqrt(b*b-l*l)
```

with `b` as 4 and `l` as 5 produces a -ve number, which is most possibly you don't want.

FWIW, root of a negative number needs imaginary part to be represented.