# scanf format warning for double

Tags: c, pointers, double, scanf

I'm having a small problem with a program I'm working on, I keep getting the warning `format '%1f' expects type 'float *' but argument 2 has type 'double *'` So I'm fairly sure it's a problem with my `scanf` format.

I've tried looking all over for a solution but can't seem to find one.

This function reads in two numbers.

```
void read(double *n1, double *d1)
{
    printf("Enter the number n1: ");
    scanf("%1f", n1);
    printf("Enter the number d1: ");
    scanf("%1f", d1);
}
```

Comment: For double you want `%lf`.  Not `%1f`.  (But it's easy to miss the difference!)

Comment: use `"%lf"`(i.e. "long float") for double

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading in double values with scanf in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730188/reading-in-double-values-with-scanf-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scanf("%lf", n1)` for `double`; Note the "l" (el, not "one").
If you are new to programming, try to get familiar with documentation, e.g. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf). There you find, for example, the matrix of format and length specifies for `scanf`.

Have fun with learning programming, use google et al, and don't hesitate to ask :-)

Comment: Thank you for the friendly attitude!

Answer (score 2):

You made a typo and then you duplicated it...

```
scanf("%1f", n1);
```

Should be written

```
scanf("%lf", n1);
```

Note the difference between `l` (lowercase L) and `1` (number one).

`%lf` stands for long float, which is not an actual C type, but a way to distinguish `float` (`%f`) and `double` (`%lf`). The `l` can be used with `d` and `i` to specify `long int` and `u` for `long unsigned int`.

These characters are difficult to distinguish, especially with fixed pitch fonts used for programming, for this very reason, one should avoid naming a variable `l`, `ll` etc. and the `long` integer constant `1l` should be written `1L`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%lf` format specifier for double data type.

Comment: I see now, i feel so dumb. been working on this for like an hour. still fairly new to programming. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use correct format specifiers for their respective data types

- `float          %f`
- `double         %lf`
- `int            %d` or `%i`
- `unsigned int   %u`
- `char           %c`
- `char *         %s`
- `long int       %ld`
- `long long int  %lld`