# Average arrays type double

Tags: c, arrays, double, mean

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int n, i;
double num[100], sum = 0.0, average;

printf("Enter the numbers of elements: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("Enter number %d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%f", &num[i]);
    sum += num[i];
}

average = sum / n;
printf("Average = %f", average);

return 0;
}
```

Hi, I have a problem with displaying the average, displaying numbers from space, how to fix it?

Comment: You should read the compiler warning, any decent compiler will tell you where is wrong and  how to fix.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730188/reading-in-double-values-with-scanf-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading in double values with scanf in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730188/reading-in-double-values-with-scanf-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Correct format specifier for double would be (you will have to use this)

```
scanf("%lf", &num[i]);
```

For `printf` both `%f` or `%lf` will do. Note that when using `scanf` check the return value of `scanf` - in case of failure you will take necessary action. (Wrong input given or some other error).

Answer (score 0):

Using the correct format specifier for double as stated by @coderredoc resolves it. Use %lf instead of %f.