# Float, Double data types confusion in external functions (C)

Tags: c, double

The code below compiles alright:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double add(double summand1, double summand2)
{
    double sum;
    sum = summand1+summand2;
    return sum;
}

double subtract(double minuend, double subtrahend)
{
    double diff;
    diff = minuend-subtrahend;
    return diff;
}

int main()
{
    double a,b,c,d;
    printf("Enter Operand 1:\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter Operand 2:\n");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    // Add
    c = add(a,b);

    // Subtract
    d = subtract(a,b);

    printf("Sum: %.3f\n", c);
    printf("Difference: %.3f\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

However, when entering `5` and `5` the result is `0.000` (wrong) and `0.000` (expected).
When entering a decimal number (e.g. `2.5`), the second prompt is skipped altogether and two random numbers are printed for `sum` and `difference`.
The problem must be with the data types double and float, which I seem to be using incorrectly.

Comment: Different data types have different format specifiers for `scanf`. You are using wrong ones.

Comment: Use `%lf` to read floating-point types in `scanf`.

Comment: @JohnBode `%lf` is for `double`. Each floating point type has its own specifier

Comment: [C - Scanf not changing value of double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46620751/995714), [Reading in double values with scanf in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13730188/995714)

Answer (score 5):

In your `scanf()`you used the format specifier `%d`which is used for integers. As you declared your whole variables as doubles use `%lf` (floating point) instead. I tried the code and with the correct specifier, the Code works.

Comment: @TimRandall See this, about format specifiers: https://codeforwin.org/2015/05/list-of-all-format-specifiers-in-c-programming.html it's the table I was always using.

Comment: Hmm. I suppose I'm thinking of printf

Comment: @TimRandall Please delete your first comment as it's wrong and may confuse some readers. Thanks

Comment: `scanf()` detail: `"%d"` match `int *` not `int`, `"%f"` match `float *`, `"%lf"` match `double *`.