C gives me zero as result of a multiplication between two doubles (the value of the doubles isn't 0)
I've written this code in C:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double molt(double *a, double *b){
        return (*a)*(*b);
    }

int main(){
    double side1;
    double side2;
    printf("Insert the length of the first side:         ");
    scanf("%f", &side1);
    printf("Insert the length of the second side:        ");
    scanf("%f", &side2);
    printf("The Area of your square or rectangle is:   %f", molt(&side1, &side2));
    return 0;
}

This is the output of my program:
Insert the length of the first side:         5
Insert the length of the second side:        5
The Area of your square or rectangle is:   0.000000

The result should be 25, but it's zero.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13730188/2287576 where it says you should use %lf and not %f since it is a double and not a float.

I changed %f with %lf and now it works properly. Thank you

<O/T> there's no reason to pass addresses of side1 and side2, better practice to do double molt(double a, double b) { return a * b; } and molt(side1, side2);

Ok thank you, effectly now the code is much readable!

Note that if you had printed side1 and side2 after the values are both entered, you'd see that your assertion "the values of the doubles isn't zero" is dubious.  It depends a bit on what format you use, but in fixed-point (%f) they probably would print as zeros.  You could use %g to get a better idea of the values — they're probably tiny.  Printing the values read by the program is a good way of ensuring that you did get what you expected to get.  And you should check the return value from scanf() before using the values — if it isn't 1, you've got problems.
