# What is wrong with usage of atof function?

Tags: c, atof

```
int main()
{
    char str[10]="3.5";
    printf("%lf",atof(str));
    return 0;
}
```

This is a simple code I am testing at ideone.com. I am getting the output as

```
-0.371627
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf).

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Not at all. `%lf` is perfectly fine for printing a `double`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have not included stdlib.h. Add proper includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char str[10]="3.5";
    printf("%lf",atof(str));
    return 0;
}
```

Without including stdlib.h, `atof()` is declare implicitly and the compiler assumes it returns an int.

Comment: OTOH, it looks like `%lf` is only proper in C99's `printf()` and not in C89's.

Comment: Thanks, this was the error. Though I never heard of this before.

Comment: Of what? Of the need to include headers or enable all warnings to see potential problems that the compiler can find?

Comment: so this is the correct answer... but can someone explain why C is allowing me to call a function that does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

It could be [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf).

Comment: no, `%lf` is the correct specifier for double, there's no issue with that. It's just that [*"If the converted value falls out of range of the return type, the return value is undefined"*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atof) which is the same reason why [`atoi()` shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)