# Division by long being truncated - C

Tags: c, timing, division, truncation

I'm attempting to time a function using the `gettimeofday()` function. I'm able to acquire the time in microseconds, but when attempting to divide it by a `long` to get time in seconds my value is truncated to a single `integer`. Does anyone have any insights as to why this is happening? I had assumed that division by a `long = 1000000.0` would prevent this kind of truncation.

Timing of function:

```
struct timeval t1,t2;

gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

// Computes C - C1 - using single thread
for (i=0; i < n; i++)
    for (j=0; j < p; j++)
    {
        C1[i][j]=0;
        for (k=0; k < m; k++)
            C1[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
    }

gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
```

Division applied here:

```
long divider = 1000000.0;
long elapsed = ((t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000000.0L) + (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec);
elapsed = (elapsed/divider);

printf("Time in seconds: %ld seconds\n", elapsed);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why are you not using double? long is an integer type.

Comment: You're aware that `long` is an integer type, aren't you?

Comment: ahhhh, i apologize. I had tested it using double, but I did not alter the format code for printf. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Long` is an integer type meaning it won't hold decimals, you probably want to use `double` for `divider` and `elapsed`. More information on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/)

Note that you'll also need `%lf` to [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) the value.

**Correction**: just `%f` as printf-format is apparently [enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4264154/249237)

Answer (score 2):

The `long` type is an integer type.

The problem is that you're trying to store a result which you want to be a `float` (or a `double`) in a `long`.

There are two problems here:
1- Your operands are never cast into `float`/`double` (implicit cast by the compiler), so all the intermediate operation returns an `int` or a `long`.
2- Your result is a `long`: even if your operands are `float`/`double`, your result will be cast to `long`.

What you have to do: use `double` variables.

```
double divider = 1000000.0;
double elapsed = ((t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000000.0) + (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec);
elapsed = (elapsed/divider);

printf("Time in seconds: %5.5f seconds\n", elapsed);
```