# QSorting an array of doubles

Tags: c, double, qsort

I'm new to using qsort, and I'm attempting to qsort a predefined array of doubles, unfortunately the result I receive is all 0's after the array has been sorted using qsort. I'm completely lost, and any advice would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code I am using to sort this array of doubles.

```
static int compare (const void * a, const void * b){
    if (*(const double*)a > *(const double*)b) return 1;
    else if (*(const double*)a < *(const double*)b) return -1;
    else return 0;  
}

double stuff[] = {255, 1, 5, 39.0};
qsort(stuff, 4, sizeof(double), compare);
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    printf("%d %s", stuff[i], " ");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the way you are printing the result with your `printf()` function. To print `double` values, you need to use `%f`, like this:

```
printf("%f ", stuff[i]);
```

Also, just a sidenote: you don't need these `else` statements in your compare function, since once the condition is evaluated as true, it will return the function.

Comment: Hah, what a simple mistake. Thanks for the help, and yes I do know that the compare function is slightly inefficient, honestly I copied and pasted it just to test out if qsort will work in the first place.

Comment: Those simple mistakes can turn out to be the toughest ones to find out sometimes :-)

Comment: Why `%lf` since there is no `long double`? `%f` should be enough here.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, the problem is in the format specifier you used with `printf()`: `%d` (which you used) is not good for `double`s; you should use something like `%f` or `%g` instead. See [this Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4264127/1629821) for more details.

Something like:

```
printf("%g ", stuff[i]);
```

should be just fine.

(Note that you don't need to pass `"%s"` and single-space string literal to `printf()` either.)

Moreover, I'd like to show you how to better write your `compare()` function:

1. You can assign the raw `void*` pointers to some constant value at the beginning of function body, to avoid repeating the (ugly) casts, and making the code clearer and more readable.
2. You may want to simplify your `if...else if...else` structure, and just use a simpler `if...return` structure.

Something like this:

```
static int compare(const void * a, const void * b) 
{
    const double lhs = *(const double *)a;
    const double rhs = *(const double *)b;

    if (lhs > rhs)
        return 1;

    if (lhs < rhs)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```