# Typecasting in C -2147483648

Tags: c, casting

I am using C, and in my program I am typecasting a variable from double to int using this code:

```
x1=(int)((x1+0.25)*2);
```

For some reason I get the value of x1 as `-2147483648.00`

What am I doing wrong?

**Full code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
double x1=-10., y1=15.,x2=10.,y2=15.,t;
int i, Y=0,X=20,j;
char check;
do {            
scanf("%c",&check);

if (check!='T')   
  break;

scanf("ime: %lf ( %lf, %lf), ( %lf, %lf)\n",&t,&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);    
printf("Time: %.1lf\n",t);

for (i=20; i>=Y; i--) {      
  printf("|");           
  for (j=-20; j<=X; j++) {
if (x1>0)   
  x1=(int)((x1+0.25)*2);   
else if (x1<0)
  x1=(int)((10-0.25)*2);
else 
  x1=0;
if (x2>0)
  x2=(int)((x2+0.25)*2);
    else if (x2<0)
  x2=(int)((x2-0.25)*2);
else 
  x2=0;
(y1>0)?(y1=(int)(y1+0.5)):(y1=(int)(y1-0.5));        
(y2>0)?(y2=(int)(y2+0.5)):(y2=(int)(y2-0.5));
if ((x1==x2)&&(x2==j)&&(y1==y2)&&(y2==i))             
  printf("*");                   
else if ((x1==j) && (y1==i))
  printf("1");
else if ((x2==j) && (y2==i))
  printf("2");
else
  printf(" ");
  } 
  printf("|\n");
}
for (i=0;i<43;i++)
  printf("-");                   
printf("\n");

printf ("x1=%.2lf, y1=%.2lf, x2=%.2lf, y2=%.2lf",x1,y1,x2,y2);
printf("\n");
}
 while (check=='T');     

return 0;
}
```

**Input:** *Without the asterisk and space*

```
Time: 0.00 ( -10.00, 20.00), ( 10.00, 20.00)
Time: 0.10 ( -8.00, 14.95), ( 8.00, 14.95)
Time: 0.20 ( -6.00, 14.80), ( 6.00, 14.80)
Time: 0.30 ( -4.00, 14.56), ( 4.00, 14.56)
Time: 0.40 ( -2.00, 14.22), ( 2.00, 14.22)
Time: 0.50 (  0.00, 13.77), ( 0.00, 13.77)
Boom!
```

Comment: What is the old value of x1?

Comment: Is the original type of x1 double or int?

Comment: the old value of x1 is 10, and x1 is a double.

Comment: I don't see how the given result is possible if `x1` is originally 10. What does `(int)((10+0.25)*2)` result in? Perhaps there is improper usage or display? A *complete* minimal test-case might be in order.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. What platform are you targeting?

Comment: Actually it results in: 19922944.00

Comment: @user2939992 Please post a *complete* (but minimal) program that reproduces the behavior and indicate the compiler/target. Something is amiss.

Comment: My best guess is that you're using an incorrect `printf` format string. Use `"%d"` for `int`, `"%g"` or `"%f"` for `double`.

Comment: How are you getting that result?  Are you using `printf("%f", x1)`, or are you (incorrectly) using `%d`?

Comment: if (x1>0)
   x1=(int)((x1+0.25)*2);   
 else if (x1<0)
   x1=(int)((10-0.25)*2);
And all is inside a loop that changes the value of x1 everytime.

Comment: @user2939992 That's not a *complete* (but minimal) program. The current consensus is that `x1` is *used incorrectly* (perhaps in printf) later. (And now, suddenly a while loop appears! This is why a *complete* test-case is required.)

Comment: I am printing using %lf

Comment: There is no `%lf` for `printf`.  Use `%f`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4264127/1553090

Comment: I am using %lf for other variables and it works perfectly.

Comment: `%lf` is valid and identical to `%f`.

Comment: @user2939992 is `x1` an `int` or a `double`?

Comment: I don't know what a test-case is, this is my first question.

Comment: @user2939992 A test-case here would be a small program that we can run to reproduce the behavior. In the case of C, it might (and for the sake of SO) all fit inside `main`.

Comment: @user2939992 Oh goodness. Now my head is exploding but it might also be related to this non-N.A. beverage - formatting is what editors are for, use it! Anyway, at least now there is much more information to go with and a test-case that can be analyzed in more detail. I've reversed my down-vote. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple one:

**You are trying to typecast `double` to `int`. whereas the `x2` is exceeding way beyond `integer range`.**
check this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/44774/

And that's why when you try to get `x2` from `int` to `double` again, it's impossible.

Try to run your program by removing typecast for `x2`, and see, it's working.

You can **truncate** `double` using `math.h` in C. Or though you can add floating values directly it will not make huge difference; but definitely not a good programming practice.

And yeah, please post program with proper indenting and formatting to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the program you have provided, it is `x2` that becomes -2,147,483,648 first, not `x1`.

When you convert a floating-point value to `int`, the C standard does not define the behavior of the integer portion of the floating-point value is not representable in the `int` type. Apparently, on the system you are using:

- The `int` type represents values from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
- Your program creates a floating-point value outside that range.
- When a value outside that range is converted to `int`, your C implementation produces -2,147,483,648.

There are two problems:

- You need to figure out why your program is producing such large values and decide whether you want to do that or not.
- When you want to take the integer part of a floating-point value, you should `#include <math.h>` and use `trunc` rather than converting it to an `int`. If you want to round to the nearest integer, use `round`, rather than adding .5 (or subtracting if negative) and taking the integer part.

Your code is essentially doubling `x1` and `x2` repeatedly, and it is not clear why or what the goal is.