# Weird math differences between MSVC and G++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, math, gcc, precision

for the whole day I've been fighting with something I believed being a bug but then (with some nasty printf-debugging) it came out that it was a weird **exp** math function behaviour ... maybe there's something I'm missing here because I really don't get it.

Could you please explain me the following behaviour:

```
#include <cmath>

printf( "%lf\n", exp( -100.0 ) ); // <--- I know this should be %e, see the edit above
```

**gcc 4.2.1** ( both on mingw and Mac OS X, both 64bit ):

```
0.000000
```

**msvc 2012** ( 64bit )

```
3.720075....e-44
```

( Where '....' are decimals I don't remember and can't test right now since I'm at home on my Mac ).

GCC flags:

```
g++ -Wall -g -pg *.cpp -o mytest
```

MSVC with default flags.

What am I missing here? Isn't **exp** a standard function with standard precision?

**EDIT 2**

Ok this seems to be related to MSVC default floating point model ( /fp:precise ) ... any chance to have the same model with GCC ? I'd like to release the project as opensource but there's not point in it if it's not gonna work with the most popular opensource compiler due to a lack of precise floating point model.

**EDIT**

Ok so I was using a wrong format for the printf call ( I should've used %e or %.50lf to print scientific notation or enough decimals ), **but** the point is that the whole project doesn't give me the expected results ( I'm developing a SVM with SMO algorithm and Gaussian kernel ) if compiled with GCC, while it works flawlessly if I compile it with MSVC (of course with no changes whatsoever ).
What could cause that?

( Picture of the **same** source code running on a Mac and on a VM with Windows 7 )

[image: Picture of the **same** source code running on a Mac and on a VM with Windows 7]

Comment: sure but you are relying on the C library to print it out and that is not a standard conversion.  if you print the raw binary value for the floating point result, if the hardware conforms to the ieee spec, then you should get the same answer.  but here again there are different rounding modes and different compilers or operating systems may have a different opinion on rounding.

Comment: why so old version of gcc?

Comment: @PiotrNycz I don't update gcc very often since it's not the compiler I use for my job, I was just playing around with it for a small Makefile based project.

Comment: What version of MSVC are you using? For a very long time, MSVC compilers have not been standard-compliant. Even now their conformance is spotty, although I think that most C99 is covered after only 15 years :-)

Comment: MSVC C support is ****ed up, I'm compiling it as C++ of course with visual studio 2012 updated to the latest revision.

Comment: `but the point is that the whole project doesn't give me the expected results`  So what is the magnitude of the differences between the two versions?  Except for the first comment by dwelch, no mention of floating point's inherent inexact nature has been mentioned.  MSVC has 3 floating point modes that can be chosen when building a program, `Precise`, `Strict`, and `Fast`.  All of these could produce differing results, and that is for the same compiler, not differing compilers.

Comment: good point, I'm using (the default) /fp:precise on MSVC ... how can I achieve the same kind of results with gcc (if possible)?

Comment: @SimoneMargaritelli I don't know if it's even possible.  Not only is floating point inexact, you have to guarantee that `exp` uses  *exactly* the same implementation on MSVC and gcc.  That is not guaranteed.  When you're using such small numbers, inexactness of floating point and differences in implementation will make it difficult to get the exact results you're looking for.

Comment: that kind of sucks, I have to use a vm to develop this and I would like to publish the SVM library as opensource ... but if it's not working with the main opensource compiler there's no point in it :(

Comment: @SimoneMargaritelli Maybe you should write your own `exp` function.  Then both compilers will be executing the same code.  I know it's a pain, but at least you will get one guarantee (same implementation) that you're not getting now.

Comment: I would do that if I knew that exp is the real problem, but since the code is way much more complex than that, at this point I'm not even sure the (compiler) problem resides there ...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you know what? I've tried with /fp:strict and /fp:fast too ... I have the same (exact) results on msvc XD

Comment: Please do try with a more recent version of gcc. Also, please show the generated asm, to see if constant folding is involved. And do update your code snippet to something that actually compiles and demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 7):

The computations are the same, you are not printing enough digits:

```
printf( "%.50lf\n", exp( -100.0 ) );
```

This [produces the following output with gcc](http://ideone.com/WCZsjG):

```
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000003720076
```

That's the 3.720076e-44

Using `%le` specifier [produces](http://ideone.com/K2ZNHn) `3.720076e-44`, too.

Comment: Alternatively, try using the `"%e"` format specifier

Comment: Or printf should use %lg to get the scientific notation if necessary. %lf should always be non-scientific.

Answer (score 0):

I just compiled and executed

```
printf("%lf\n", exp(-100.0));
```

in my Dell Laptop (Windows 7, 64 bit and Visual Studio 2012) and my Macbook Pro (Mountain Lion, 64 bit and XCode). Both are displaying

```
0.000000
```

as the result.

Are you sure, you didn't change the format specifier in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using the default /fp:precise flag with Visual Studio 2012 too and the output is consistent with Mac. Perhaps you should try running the code in a real PC, instead of VirtualBox. Also if want to publish your code as open source library, I guess you won't be going to use the printf functions (unless you want to show test cases) in them and just let the end user select appropriate precisions and appropriate format specifiers.

Comment: I've tried the code on a real pc (@ my office), I've used the VM just to show the differences while @ home .... what gcc and msvc versions are you using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2012 on Windows, and Apple LLVM 5.0 in Mac OS.

Comment: I've an older gcc ( 4.2.1 ) ... btw I've tried with /fp:strict and /fp:fast too ... I have the same (exact) results on msvc XD

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting the error. The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ecbz014.aspx) does not have any reference of %lf specifier. So I'm assuming that VS 2012 should just treat it as %f specifier (with 6 digit precision). Similar argument is made in this [stackoverflow page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf). So, I guess, if you want more precision just use %le or %lg specifiers as pointed out by @dasblinkenlight.

Comment: the problem is not the printf specifier, even with the correct one I have different (wrong) results on the same exact code while MSVC compiled version gives correct result due to /fp:precise floating point model ... so now it's just a matter of "how do I replicate /fp:precise with GCC?

Comment: Also, I didn't see the problematic code and output in your Visual Studio snapshot.

Comment: dude are you reading what I'm writing you? It's not a matter of format specifier, that's old story now, the real issue is floating point model XD

Comment: O.o ... I made the second comment without refreshing the screen. By the way, I can guarantee that /fp:precise is not causing the output to differ either. Hope you find the answer soon. Would like to see your SVM implementation some day.

Comment: yeah even with others /fp models the output is always correct ... quite weird!