# Scanf not behaving as expected

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to use `scanf()` to input values to a structure using pointers.Can you help me to understand why my code is not working

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct student
{
   int no;
   float marks;
}st[2],*s;

main()
{
  printf("enter the values");
  for(s=st;s<st+2;s++)
  {
    scanf("%d%d",&s->no,&s->marks);
  }
  for(s=st;s<st+2;s++)
  {
    printff("%d\t%d\t",s->no,s->marks);
  }
}
```

in this code scanf is not working properly,it is taking only the first value

Comment: it's better to format your codes properly.

Comment: `main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: Voting to close as simple typo, wrong format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong format specifier. `%d` is used for `int`s while `%f` is used for `float`s. Use

```
scanf("%d%f",&s->no,&s->marks);
```

and

```
printf("%d\t%f\t",s->no,s->marks);
```

instead as `s->marks` is a `float`, not an `int`. Using the wrong format specifier leads to Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include<stdio.h>
     struct student
       {
      int no;
      float marks;
         }st[2],*s;


 main()
  {
 printf("enter the values");
 for(s=st;s<st+2;s++)
  {
 scanf("%d%f",&s->no,&s->marks);
  }
 for(s=st;s<st+2;s++)
   {
  printf("%d\t%f\t",s->no,s->marks);
    }
   }
```

U have to use %f for float

Answer (score 0):

In the structure you have taken two variable one is `int` type and other is `float` type but while doing `scanf`(taking input) you are doing `%d` for `float` whereas it should be `%f` for float .This is a very minor mistake but you should try to avoid it on your own by just looking at your code carefully :)

Happy coding

Comment: `%f` is for double actually :)

Comment: check this http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Standard_C_Library/Functions/printf

Comment: Study about "default argument promotion rule of C", or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf)