# Output not match the code in c (double variable)

Tags: c, double, output

I am new with c and I'm trying to use doubles variable. Unfortunately, the compiler (Code::Blocks) seems to ignore absolutely what i'm writing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double x=1.03;
    printf("x: %lf",x);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
x: 0.000000
```

what is the problem?

Comment: I don't see the problem. http://ideone.com/LUKwif.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots! You are expected to provide your question as text with proper formatting, unless its nature requires an image, of course.

Comment: Got it. from now on i won't post screenshots.

Comment: I also can't reproduce this behaviour. I'm not sure what could be wrong. Perhaps it might help to let Code::Blocks remove and rebuild the program? Or reset its settings to the defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%f` instead of `%lf`.  Doubles only need `%f`; see the "specifiers" table [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

If `printf` is looking for a larger value than you are providing, what prints out will be affected by what happens to be in memory near the `x` argument that you provided.  In this case, I'm guessing that's `0`.

**Edit**: Thanks to @Olaf for pointing out that the [specification](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p7) says `%lf` should work just fine.  Apparently the OP's compiler or compiler version is nonstandard.  Alternatively, perhaps the project settings are selecting nonstandard compiler behaviour.  (I suppose the compiler or library implementation of `printf` could be buggy, as well.)

Comment: `%lf` is fine for `double` arguments. Actually it is even a good idea to use it, as it is symmetric to `scanf`.

Comment: Maybe for c99 %lf doesn't work? i work with c99 standard

Comment: `%lf` should work too, says [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4264154/824425).

Comment: @user3579269: It was **introduced** with C99 actually.

Comment: @cxw: Please read in the standard: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p7

Comment: now that I repalced the "%lf" to "%f" it is working. but i don't sure if %f give the same result as %lf is expected to give

Comment: @user3579269: So you are using a non-standard compliant compiler.

Comment: yes sorry this is the first time i asked question on this site @Olaf

Comment: @cxw: Please have a look at the type-modifier table in the page you linked. That contradicts your answer, too.

Comment: @Olaf I was looking at the "specifiers" table, in which the entry for `%lf` is blank.  Where are you looking?  I'm sorry to say I'm not seeing what you're pointing to.

Comment: @cxw: Hmm, you are right. Now I know why cppreference has such a bad reputation. It is actually wrong. See the link I provided. Or do you claim cppreference is the mandatory reference, not the official standard document? "l (ell)
- Specifies that a following ... or has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier."

Comment: @Olaf I claim nothing :) .  I have no argument with the specification, but in this situation it appears the specification is not relevant since the OP has a non-compliant compiler.  What I care about is that the OP is able to move forward with his program.  I'm now going to clear out some of my previous comments so this doesn't look so much like a chat log ;) .  Thanks for the spec link and clarification!

Comment: @cxw: Thanks for the edit. DV removed. But please change the Code::blocks reference. That is an IDE, not a compiler. We still don't know which compiler OP uses. But he might set an option for the compiler to make it compiant.