# Reading double values from file gives output s -0000.0000 only

Tags: c++, c, file

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     #include<stdlib.h>
     #include<io.h>
     #include<conio.h>

     extern _floatconvert;
     #pragma extref _floatconvert
      void main()
      { 
           FILE *in,*out;
           double f;
           in = fopen("A.txt","r");
           out = fopen("S.txt","w");
           for (int i=0;i<18;i++)
           {
            for (int j=0;j<18;j++)
             {
               fscanf(in,"%.15lf",&f);
               fprintf(stdout,"%.15lf",f);
               getch();
               fprintf(out,"A=[%d][%d] = %lf ;",i,j,f);
              }
             }
            fclose(in);
            fclose(out); 
            getch();

           }
```

I would like to read from the file and save it to another by modifying as the code is indicating.

The input file is:

`3.53448000000 -4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 -4.77154800002 1.71775730005 0.00000000000 -8.58878640004 4.77154800002 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 7.06896000000 -4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 -8.58878640004 4.77154800002 1.71775730005 0.00000000000 -8.58878640004 4.77154800002 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 7.06896000000 -4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 -8.58878640004 -4.77154800002 1.71775730005 0.00000000000 -8.58878640004 4.77154800002 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 7.06896000000 -4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 -8.58878640004 -4.77154800002 1.71775730005 0.00000000000 8.58878640004 4.77154800002 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 7.06896000000 -4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 8.58878640004 -4.77154800002 1.71775730005 0.00000000000 -8.58878640004 4.77154800002 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 7.06896000000 4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 -8.58878640004 -4.77154800002 1.71775730005 0.00000000000 -8.58878640004 4.77154800002 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 7.06896000000 -4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 -8.58878640004 -4.77154800002 1.71775730005 0.00000000000 -8.58878640004 4.77154800002 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 7.06896000000 -4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 -8.58878640004 -4.77154800002 1.71775730005 0.00000000000 4.77154800002 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 4.77154800002 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 7.06896000000 1.76724000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 4.77154800002 1.76724000000 3.53448000000`

The output I get is:

`A=[0][0] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][1] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][2] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][3] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][4] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][5] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][6] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][7] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][8] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][9] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][10] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][11] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][12] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][13] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][14] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][15] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][16] = -0.000000 ;A=[0][17] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][0] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][1] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][2] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][3] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][4] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][5] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][6] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][7] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][8] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][9] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][10] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][11] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][12] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][13] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][14] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][15] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][16] = -0.000000 ;A=[1][17] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][0] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][1] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][2] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][3] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][4] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][5] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][6] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][7] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][8] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][9] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][10] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][11] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][12] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][13] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][14] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][15] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][16] = -0.000000 ;A=[2][17] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][0] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][1] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][2] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][3] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][4] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][5] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][6] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][7] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][8] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][9] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][10] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][11] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][12] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][13] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][14] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][15] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][16] = -0.000000 ;A=[3][17] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][0] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][1] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][2] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][3] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][4] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][5] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][6] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][7] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][8] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][9] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][10] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][11] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][12] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][13] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][14] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][15] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][16] = -0.000000 ;A=[4][17] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][0] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][1] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][2] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][3] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][4] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][5] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][6] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][7] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][8] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][9] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][10] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][11] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][12] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][13] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][14] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][15] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][16] = -0.000000 ;A=[5][17] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][0] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][1] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][2] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][3] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][4] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][5] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][6] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][7] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][8] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][9] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][10] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][11] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][12] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][13] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][14] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][15] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][16] = -0.000000 ;A=[6][17] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][0] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][1] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][2] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][3] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][4] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][5] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][6] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][7] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][8] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][9] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][10] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][11] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][12] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][13] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][14] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][15] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][16] = -0.000000 ;A=[7][17] = -0.000000 ; ... .. .`

All zeroes. Why?

Comment: Please, reduce your output (number of iterations) to minimal with which problem is still presented.

Comment: Not exactly impressed by the error checking.  You don't check in, out or the value returned by scanf().  Also, what @GeorgeSovetov says.  Why can you not just read one value from the input file and get that working first?  Why all that gunge?

Comment: Also try stuff.  Try %f instead of %lf

Comment: Also, debugger....................................

Comment: More simply: 'ALL ZEROES!! WHY!!' - because you do not seem to have taken any debugging action at all:((

Comment: Try reading with `lf` instead of `.15lf`

Comment: Why is this tagged both C and C++? Why are you using `void main()` rather than the correct `int main(void)` (for C) or `int main()` (for C++)?

Comment: not really into c programming. just care for the output cause i want to feed that as a test vector to my vivado design.

Comment: what debugging actions??

Answer (score 3):

You are giving `fscanf` function wrong format specifier. You don't need to specify precision when scanning, so instead of writing `fscanf(in,"%.15lf",&f);` you should write `fscanf(in,"%lf",&f);`

Comment: Checking the result of `fscanf() == 1` is recommended to insure that a successful scan occurred.

Comment: Thanks! my bad, stupid error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about scanf to help you out there, but here is an equivalent C++ program using streams that does what you want.

```
#include<fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream in("A.txt");
    std::ofstream out("S.txt");

    if (!in) { /* Error opening in */ }
    if (!out) { /* Error opening out */ }

    out.setf(std::ios::fixed);

    for (int r = 0; r < 18; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 18; c++) {
             double f;
             in >> f;
             out << "A=[" << r << "][" << c << "] = " << f << " ;";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `double f = 0.0; if (in >> f) { out << "A=[" /*...*/; } else { /* Error reading value */ }`

Comment: @Pixelchemist Aye that is even better, but I decided to drop that level of error-checking for this example.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `%lf` for `fprintf`.

Try just using `%f`.

More information here [Correct format specifier for double in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf)