# Error in C concerning double, float variable assignment

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double height; //Error happens if I write double height instead of float height! 
    printf("Height(inch): ");
    scanf("%f",&height);
    printf("%f inch = %f cm \n",height,height*2.54);
}
```

As you can see in the comment, error happens if I write double height instead of float height! What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What from the man-page of `scanf` did you not understand?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf Read (at least the last part of) the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%f` format specifier for `scanf` expects a pointer to a `float`, not a `double`.  This is significant because the two are different sizes.  Passing in the address of a `double` will result in some but not all of the bytes comprising the `double` to be populated, resulting in undefined behavior.

To read a value into a `double`, use `%lf`.

```
double height;
scanf("%lf",&height);
```