# Unable to use double variable in C++ using cstdio

Tags: c++, c, c++11, stdio, cstdio

C++ code for double using cstdio header.

```
#include <cstdio>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
    
            double f;
            scanf("%lf",&f);
            printf("%lf",f);
            
            return 0;
    }
```

**This code always output 0.000000. Why? But similar code works well in C**

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main() {
            double f;
            scanf("%lf",&f);
            printf("%lf",f);
            return 0;
    }
```

This code works Fine.

Comment: `printf("%lf",f);` --> `printf("%f",f);`

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://ideone.com/MsqXCs - Could you please tell which compiler you're using, and which input data you test with ?

Comment: Code working in ideone doesn't prove anything in the general case. `long double` and `double` may or may not have different representation in a particular execution environment.

Comment: an exact duplicate: [Correct format specifier for double in printf](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4264127/995714)

Comment: this is codeblocks compiler.. I don't know why this happen. but i am unable to reproduce on another PC and online ide.

Comment: using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior. The fact that it works on 1 or 2 computers doesn't mean that it'll work on others

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation of `fscanf` and `fprintf` (especially the conversion specifiers, they differ) and remove the `using namespace std`.