# double data type in matrix

Tags: c, types

I need to build a matrix. And I need to use double data type. At the same time, 
the data will be entered by the user. But when the data is entered; compiler program say: "ARRAY SUBSCRIPT IS AN NOT INTEGER". But I need use double data.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double matris[3][4];
    double i;
    double j;
    printf("Please Enter Number for Matris:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            scanf("%lf", &matris[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%f", &matris[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: You need `double` for the items, not the indices.

Comment: And you really need to format your code, but really

Comment: Then you should make them integers.

Comment: `double i;
    double j;` --> `int i, j;`, `printf("%f", &matris [i][j]);` --> `printf("%f ", matris [i][j]);`

Comment: Just for you to think things through, what would mean `matris[0.3782][16.777]`? (That is, why would you want to make the indices a non-integer?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array subscript is how to index into an array. 
It is not the same as the type of the data in the array.

Furthermore, watch out for the format specifier and what you are printing when you output the array afterwards. Don't print the address.

```
int main() {
    double matris[3][4];
    int i;//<------
    int j;//<------


    printf("Please Enter Number for Matris:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            scanf("%lf", &matris[i][j]);
        }
    }


    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%f ", matris[i][j]); //<------
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it correct to write %f in place of %lf in the line `printf("%f ", matris[i][j]);`

Comment: @Sanjay-sopho I believe so (scanf is different) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf

Comment: Thanks. Got something cleared.