# Adding doubles in ansi C produces unexpected results

Tags: c

For my school project we are required to do math with doubles. My current code produces some unexpected results.

```
/* Hello World program */

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

double result = 0.0;
double x;
x = 10.0;

result = x + 10.0;

printf("%d", result);

return 0;

}
```

Upon running, this code prints: "-1267258024"

I don't understand why this happens? Why does the code not print 20.0?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm so dumb. %d is for floats. Thank you!

Comment: `%d` is for integers.

Comment: Using the wrong [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I am so dumb. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
printf("%d", result);
```

indicates that you want to print an integer.

You probably want

```
printf("%f", result);
```

There are also things like `%lf` (acts the same as `%f`) and `%Lf` (works for long doubles) which you can read about on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf).

A complete list of formatting options can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).