# How to save a process id on a global variable?

Tags: c, process

i want save the current process id on a variable.

So, i do this:

```
double id = 0; //Global variable

.....

id = getpid();

printf("%d %d", id, getpid()); // the result ins't the same...
```

Well, i expected save the current process id on a global variable.

Edit:

```
new_pid = fork();
//new_pid2 = fork();
switch(new_pid) {
case -1:
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(1);
case 0:
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
        signal(SIGUSR1, trata_SIGSEGV);
        break;
default:
        signal(SIGUSR1, trata_SIGSEGV);
        kill(new_pid, SIGUSR1);
        break;
}
break;
```

Comment: Why is your variable id a double ? The variable returned by getpid is an int like.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you added in the edit? A possible problem is that you might be sending the signal before the other process has called `signal()` to establish the handler. Try calling `signal()` before you fork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're printing `id` with the wrong format. You should either use `%f`:

```
printf("%f %d", id, getpid());
```

[Correct format specifier for double in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf)

or cast it to `int`:

```
printf("%d %d", (int)id, getpid());
```

A better idea would be to use the correct type when declaring `id`:

```
pid_t id;
```

This is an integer type, rather than a floating point type.

Comment: But then i'll be able to send the id on a kill command?
Like kill(id, SIGUSR1);

Comment: All the functions that deal with process IDs use `pid_t` as the datatype.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work. Make sure you've included the proper headers.

Comment: Don't, i'll edit the post with the code that don't work

Comment: What does any of this have to do with `printf()`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the use of `printf`. Your id variable is of type `double`, and you pass that to `printf` when it's expecting an `int`. This will completely break the result.

Replace

```
double id = 0;
```

with

```
long id;
```

to keep it as an integral type.

Also, replace

```
printf("%d %d", id, getpid());
```

with

```
printf("%ld %ld", id, (long) getpid());
```

to ensure that the expected type is being passed to printf.

Also, no need to initialize `id` to 0 since you unconditionally assign to it later.